# Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified when using X server

Tags: ssh, xserver

I am trying to access GUIs from my Ubuntu 22 server.
On my Windows 11 cmd with Xming installed (which I don't think I need). I run ssh -X me@myserver. Then in bash I type firefox and get the following result:

`Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified`

If I set DISPLAY to localhost 0.0, it says:

`Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused Error: cannot open display: :0.0`

Do I need an actual display plugged in my server?

Related question:

https://superuser.com/questions/1722546/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-server-guis-from-a-local-network-windows-11-pc

Comment: You need to allow access to the X server with `xhost +me`, read `man xhost` Is there an X server running on your "Ubuntu 22 server"?

Comment: how can I find my local network's machine name? arp-scan only gives ipv4 and mac address I think

Comment: after adding my ip, I get the following error: `xhost:  unable to open display ""`